# MYSQL SELECT OBTENER VALOR INICIAL, FINAL Y DIFERENCIA DE UN VALOR NUMERICO EN LOS ÚLTIMOS 30 DÍAS

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

antes de explicar el problema que estoy teniendo os dejo las 3 tablas que estoy usando para realizar la query.

Tabla **artist** Guarda la información de un artista de Spotify.

| id | name | Spotify_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shakira | 0EmeFodog0BfCgMzAIvKQp |
| 2 | Bizarrap | 716NhGYqD1jl2wI1Qkgq36 |

Tabla **platform_information** Guardar la información que quiero obtener de los artistas y en que plataforma.

| id | platform | information |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | spotify | monthly_listeners |
| 2 | spotify | followers |

Tabla **platform_information_artist** Almacena la información de cada artista en una plataforma y una información en una fecha concreta.

| id | platform_information_id | artist_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-11-01 | 100000 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2022-11-15 | 101000 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2022-11-30 | 102000 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2022-11-02 | 85000 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 2022-11-06 | 90000 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 2022-11-26 | 100000 |

Dada la siguiente información, necesito una query con la que pueda obtener por cada artista el **value** inicial y final de los últimos 30 días, la **difference** entre el inicio de mes y el final de mes, el nombre del artista, el id del artista y el id de la plataforma. También necesito obtenerlos ordenados de mayor **difference** a menor y con un limite de 5 artistas.

| artist_id | platform_information_id | month_start_value | month_end_value | difference | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 85000 | 100000 | 15000 | Bizarrap |
| 1 | 1 | 100000 | 102000 | 2000 | Shakira |

Actualmente no consigo pasar de la siguiente query:

```
SELECT artist.name, artist.id, pia.platform_information_id, pia.date, pia.value FROM artist 
RIGHT JOIN platform_information_artist as pia
ON artist.id = pia.artist_id 
WHERE pia.platform_information_id = (SELECT id from platform_information WHERE platform = 'spotify' AND information = 'monthly_listeners')  
    AND DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 31 DAY
ORDER BY artist.id, pia.date ASC ;
```

| name | id | platform_information | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shakira | 1 | 1 | 2022-11-01 | 100000 |
| Shakira | 1 | 1 | 2022-11-15 | 101000 |
| Shakira | 1 | 1 | 2022-11-30 | 102000 |
| Bizarrap | 2 | 1 | 2022-11-02 | 85000 |
| Bizarrap | 2 | 1 | 2022-11-06 | 90000 |
| Bizarrap | 2 | 1 | 2022-11-26 | 100000 |

Devuelve la información de cada Artista en los últimos 30 días pero desconozco como obtener solo 1 fila por artista con los campos indicados anteriormente y ordenador de mayor diferencia a menor y con un límite de 5 artistas.

También he conseguido hacer esta query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT value FROM platform_information_artist 
        WHERE artist_id = 1 AND platform_information_id = (SELECT id from platform_information WHERE platform = 'spotify' AND information = 'monthly_listeners') 
        AND DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1) as month_start, 
    (SELECT value FROM platform_information_artist 
        WHERE artist_id = 1 AND platform_information_id = (SELECT id from platform_information WHERE platform = 'spotify' AND information = 'monthly_listeners') 
        AND DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) as month_end, 
     (SELECT month_end-month_start) as diference ORDER BY month_start;
```

Que me devuelve:

| month_start | month_end | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000 | 102000 | 2000 |

El problema de esta query es que no se como adaptarla para que me devuelva los 5 artistas ordenados de mayor **difference** a menor

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: tenes que usar group by, max, min y hacer una resta para lo que falta..

Comment: Con MIN, MAX ¿no obtendría el valor mas grande y el mas pequeño? Necesito que sea el valor de hace 30 días con el de hoy, independientemente de que este sea mayor o menor.

Comment: max fecha ;) min fecha ;) para obtener esas filas ;)

Comment: SI hago un MIN de fecha y un MAX de fecha obtengo la fecha máxima y la fecha mínima. pero no puedo obtener el valor. Si hago el min y el max del valor, me devuelve el valor máximo y mínimo independientemente de que sea hace 30 días o 5 días. No entiendo muy bien si se refiere a esto o a otra cosa. Esta es la query: SELECT MIN(pia.date) as month_start_value, MAX(pia.date) as month_end_value, artist.id, artist.name FROM artist 
RIGHT JOIN ...

Comment: se usa max y min junto con group by, para obtener los registros que despues podes unir con la misma tabla para obtener los otros datos, o podes usar funciones ventana para hacerlo tambien..

Comment: He conseguido obtener esos valores haciendo sub select con los valores, no se si será la mejor opción. SELECT
       (SELECT value FROM platform_information_artist WHERE platform_information_artist.artist_id = pia.artist_id AND platform_information_artist.platform_information_id = pia.platform_information_id AND platform_information_artist.date = MIN(pia.date)) as month_start_value,